# How can I make an if statement include a range of numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is my first time ever coding and I'm having some trouble. Here is my code so far (javascript)

```js
var userName = prompt("Hi! What is your name?"); // The answer the user gives for this prompt will be used later in the program

var hoursWorked = prompt("How many hours have you worked this week?"); //The answer the user gives for this prompt will be multiplied by 15 to determine the amount that they will be paid
var pay = ("$" + hoursWorked * 15)
var hoursLeft = (40 - hoursWorked); //This equation determines how many hours of work the user has left to complete
if (hoursLeft < 0) {
  alert("Uh oh! " + userName + "! That's too many hours!")
}; //If the user enters an amount of hours that is over 40 they will recieve an error message
if (hoursLeft === 0) {
  alert("Congratulations, " + userName + "! You have completed all 40 hours of work!"); //If the user has completed 40 hours of work they will be given this message
  alert(userName + ", your pay will be: " + pay)
};
if (hoursLeft => 0 && hoursLeft = < 39) {
  alert(userName + ", you have " + hoursLeft + " more hours to work this week."); //If the user has completed <40 hours of work they will be given this message, along with how many hours they have left to complete
  alert(userName + ", your pay so far is: " + pay)
};
if (hoursLeft > 40) {
  alert(userName + "! That is not possible!")
} //If the user enters a negative amount of hours they will be given this message
```

My problem is with this line "if (hoursLeft => 0 && hoursLeft =< 39 ){  "

How can I make it so if the hours are over 0 and less than 40 it will return the alerts? Thank you

Comment: The operator is "greater than or equal to". So change it to >= instead if =>. Same with less than or equal to, change to <=

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I've tidied the code in the snippet and it doesn't look like the `if`s are "waterfall" just some weird placement of closing braces.

Comment: Yeah, didn't see that; eyes get rusty with this white stack-overflow. Solution is just adjusting some of the statements and operator! :)

Comment: I will be apreciated if my answer help you and you accept it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you should use `>=` instead of `=>` (this will be parsed as expression for arrow function) and use `<=` instead of `=<`.

> `<=`
> Less than or equal operator.

> `>=`
> Greater than or equal operator.

Check more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

```js
var userName = prompt("Hi! What is your name?"); // The answer the user gives for this prompt will be used later in the program

var hoursWorked = prompt("How many hours have you worked this week?");  //The answer the user gives for this prompt will be multiplied by 15 to determine the amount that they will be paid
var pay = ("$" + hoursWorked * 15)  
var hoursLeft = (40 - hoursWorked); //This equation determines how many hours of work the user has left to complete
    if (hoursLeft < 0){
      alert ("Uh oh! " + userName + "! That's too many hours!")}; //If the user enters an amount of hours that is over 40 they will recieve an error message
    if (hoursLeft === 0){
      alert ("Congratulations, " + userName + "! You have completed all 40 hours of work!"); //If the user has completed 40 hours of work they will be given this message
      alert  ( userName + ", your pay will be: " + pay)}; 
    if (hoursLeft >= 0 && hoursLeft <= 39 ){  
       alert (userName + ", you have " + hoursLeft + " more hours to work this week."); //If the user has completed <40 hours of work they will be given this message, along with how many hours they have left to complete
      alert  ( userName + ", your pay so far is: " + pay)}; 
    if (hoursLeft > 40){
      alert (userName + "! That is not possible!")}
```

Answer (score 1):

greater than or equal in js show with `>=` operator, and less than or equal show with `<=` operator, see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than_or_equal) for greater than and equal and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than_or_equal) for less than and equal.

```
>=   greater than and equal

<=   less than and equal
```